# Commit without changes

Tags: git, merge, commit

I have a commit that borke my site:

```
commit 7745ace83eff751025526b7a998406e5b5d1873d
Merge: 9e79649 09e570a
Date:   Thu Feb 19 17:07:03 2015 -0300

    Merge branch 'desarrollo' of git+ssh://192.168.1.200/home/git/project into dev

commit 9e79649a64ef9925655167a8e237d5fd36fad51e
Date:   Thu Feb 19 17:06:24 2015 -0300

    Comment. Blah... Blah...

 dir/file.inc        |    1 +
 db/file2.sql    |  327 ++++++-----------------------------------
 file3.php                      |    7 +-
 file4.php                     |    1 +
 admin/file5.php |    8 +
 admin/file6.php      |    6 +-
 admin/file7.php     |   12 +-
 7 files changed, 78 insertions(+), 284 deletions(-)
```

If a change to the commit 7745ace83eff751025526b7a998406e5b5d1873d, then the site is broken.
In commit 9e79649a64ef9925655167a8e237d5fd36fad51e, the site doesn't have the bug.

How can I know which files change in commit 7745ace83eff751025526b7a998406e5b5d1873d?

Comment: You can use [git diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, just `git show COMMIT-ID` will show you the changes introduced by the commit COMMIT-ID.

However, this commit is a special case, because it is a merge commit. For merge commits, `git show` will only show changes *relative to the two ancestor commits* (the commits being merged). So if the merge resolved cleanly (without conflicts), `git show MERGE-COMMIT-ID` will show nothing.

For a merge commit, you can use `git diff`, specifying either of the ancestor commits and the merge commit. In your case, to compare the two commits you name:

```
git diff 9e79649 7745ace8
```

For both `git diff` and `git show`, you can use parameter `--stat` to only see a summary of changes -- useful for a quick overview.

Comment: `git show` also supports a `-m` option which does what you would expect. Showing a proper diff for the changes the merge commit introduced.

Answer (score 3):

The commit that you are looking at is a merge commit.  It doesn't necessarily have "changes" in the same sense as other commits.  It is the combination of changes from two other commits `9e79649` & `09e570a`.

If the bug is not present in `9e79649`, I would also check to see if it was present in `09e570a` (the other parent commit of the merge) before trying to dig into the changes in the merge commit.

The commit message is the default for a regular merge so it doesn't look like there are any conflicts that are resolved.  If there were conflicts, git would have appended them to the commit message (provided the `-m` option was not used) and you would know which files to look into.